# ERROR: Could not connect to lockdownd, error code -12

Tags: ios

I have a locked iPhone whose iOS version is 16.4 When I connected it , with a cable , to my Windows 10 64 bit Laptop and run LIBIMOBILEDEVICE **ideviceinfo -s** command in  UBUNTU virtual machine Terminal installed in VIRTUAL BOX in my Laptop, the command worked fine and I get all the info about my locked iPhone . However , when I run **idevicediagnostics restart** to restart my locked iPhone , I get this error :

**ERROR: Could not connect to lockdownd, error code -12**

I searched days and days about the above error but I could not find anything except this sentence :

LOCKDOWN_E_MISSING_VALUE = -12, took from this file in github:

https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/blob/master/include/libimobiledevice/lockdown.h#L37-L81

Moreover , I looked in LIBIMOBILEDEVICE official website and read the documentation and faq sections  but I could not find any solution to the above error

I am stuck and confuse. Could you please tell me how to run the
**idevicediagnostics restart** command successfully  without getting the above error ?! Best regards